# How to delete options in Select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I delete all options from `<select>` element using jQuery?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("selectClass").find('option').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select option').remove()
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.

Comment: Oh sure, Will do that in future.